# Java embedded browser with resources in memory

Tags: java, html, browser, swt, xulrunner

We have a Java desktop app with an embedded browser, now using XULRunner (Firefox engine) on SWT. This browser's API allows us to load webs specifying an URI or its HTML content.
What we need is to load HTML webpages including resources but being everything in memory. The best solution would be to provide a listener used when the engine tries to load resources so we can send it the appropriate content.

Any ideas? thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need a small HTTP / web server. There is [Jetty](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/), there are also a few smaller ones, just search for "small java web server" or so.

Comment: We think about that, but we prefer to avoid deploying a 'mini' web app on the client

Answer (score 0):

In HTML 5 your can put your resources inside the HTML itself.

So you can use SWT with browser that supports HTML 5 and prepare your webpages to have resources inside HTML 5.

With SWT Browser your can simply do `browser.setText(html)` to load the page from memory.